# Batch loop for a duration of time

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that infinitely runs a set of commands using GOTO LABEL. I would like to turn this into a loop that runs for a predetermined number of minutes. What is the best way to do that under Windows XP and up?

Comment: It is possible to use simpler kludges if you can assume that the number of minutes is less than say 60. Knowing the actual limits of the task would determine if that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the `time` variable at the beginning and add the desired minutes.
Then you need to cheack in each loop if the stop time is reached.

```
set "startTime=%time%"
Split the time into Hour, minutes, seconds
Add the desired minutes regarding overflows to the hour field.

Begin your loop
Parse the current time
Check if Hours and minutes are reached
Else restart the loop
```

Comment: Easier said than done.  Here's a site that shows how to convert date/time to Julian values, which you can use to do as Jeb suggests.  http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsDateTime.php